# How can I use less ram? Texture and model loading

Tags: c++, opengl, glad, stb-image

So I am following the opengl tutorial at https://learnopengl.com/Model-Loading/Model and when I run the application it is using a little more than half a gigabyte for textures and models! But when I check the size on disk of all the textures and the model file its only ~30MB on disk?

How can I make it so I use less ram? I think the issue has something to do with loading the texture or the model, but I'm not sure why it is using so much ram. This is the texture loading function:

```cpp
unsigned int TextureFromFile(const char* path, const std::string& directory, bool gamma)
{
    std::string filename = std::string(path);
    filename = directory + '/' + filename;

    unsigned int textureID;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);

    int width, height, nrComponents;
    unsigned char* data = stbi_load(filename.c_str(), &width, &height, &nrComponents, 0);
    if (data)
    {
        GLenum format;
        if (nrComponents == 1)
            format = GL_RED;
        else if (nrComponents == 3)
            format = GL_RGB;
        else if (nrComponents == 4)
            format = GL_RGBA;

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, format, width, height, 0, format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        stbi_image_free(data);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Texture failed to load at path: " << path << std::endl;
        stbi_image_free(data);
    }

    return textureID;
}
```

The tutorial's source code can be found [here](https://github.com/JoeyDeVries/LearnOpenGL/tree/master/src/3.model_loading/1.model_loading).

Comment: Compression? That might account for a lot.

Comment: "*when I run the application it is using a little more than half a gigabyte for textures and models*" How do you know that?

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2022 and it tells me how much ram the application is using

Comment: @JesperJuhl Compression, is there some documentation or tutorial for that?

Comment: What are the pixel dimensions and bit-depth of the texture? If it's a large image, it's going to take up a lot of memory, that's just how it works.

Comment: @tadman Dimensions of 4096 x 4096 and idk what a bit-depth is but probably 4? jpg? I didn't know it would take up so much memory. But there are games with thousands of textures that only use ~1.5GB?

Comment: 3 textures * 4096x4096 pixels * 4 bytes/pixel * 1.5 for mipmaps ~= 288 MiB of image data alone.

Comment: There is the idea of asset streaming, where a game can dynamically load/unload assets and their respective LODs from memory depending on some priority measure / memory budget.